# requirejs shim lost after path is updated

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am trying to feature flag ckeditor by changing the path dynamically.  It is originally set but if a flag is turned on I try to change it.
When I do not change the path, the shim works fine and ckeditor is resolved.  When I do change the path after checking the flag,  ckeditor is undefined.

config.js

```
require.config({
paths: {
    ...
    ckeditor_core: 'lib/ckeditor/ckeditor',
    ...
},
shim: {
    ...
    ckeditor_core: {
        exports: 'CKEDITOR'
    },
    ...
}
});

if (jx && jx.activeFeatures && !jx.activeFeatures.CKEDITOR_4) {
    require.config({
        map : {
            '*' : {
                'ckeditor_core' :  ''lib/ckeditor-old/ckeditor''
            }
        });
}
}
define({});
```

I have tried making this change to the map in a few different places but I am always getting this same issue:

```
TypeError: ckeditor is undefined
```

To me it seems like the shim is broken after I set the path again.  While I am in the console I am able to resolve CKEDITOR just fine.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the `map` configuration you use:

```
map: {
    '*': {
        'ckeditor_core':  'lib/ckeditor-old/ckeditor'
    }
}
```

When this map is in effect and RequireJS encounters a request for the module `ckeditor_core`, the first thing it does is replace this request with a request for `lib/ckeditor-old/ckeditor`. Then RequireJS checks for a shim. Since `lib/ckeditor-old/ckeditor` has no shim defined for it, but this is a module which *needs* a shim, then the value of the module is `undefined`. What you need to do is add a shim for it:

```
'lib/ckeditor-old/ckeditor': {
    exports: 'CKEDITOR'
},
```

Comment: Great, that worked for me.  I added a new path called 'ckeditor_core_old' and then added a shim for 'ckeditor_core_old'.